Ubuntu 24.04 hibernation does not restore state
I followed a guide (https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/) to enable hibernation. At first I had an issue that system won't hibernate after "systemctl hibernate" and instead wake up immediately. After looking in dmesg for PM-related issues, I found suspicious errors about xhci_hcd - seems like it woke up the system immediately. By toggling XHCI in /proc/acpi/wakeup (echo "XHCI" > /proc/acpi/wakeup) prior to hibernation, I was finally able to hibernate, but When I power on the PC afterwards, the saved state is not restored and the system starts afresh.
After going on the journal I see that XHCI might although be the culprit of image not being restored:
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 10%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 20%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 30%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 40%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 50%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 60%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 70%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 80%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 90%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading progress: 100%
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image loading done
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: hibernation: Read 3133032 kbytes in 2.52 seconds (1243.26 MB/s)
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: Image successfully loaded
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PM: pci_pm_freeze(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_freeze+0x0/0xf0 returns -16
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PM: failed to quiesce async: error -16
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
user-NUC14RVK-B kernel: PM: hibernation: Failed to load image, recovering.

What am I missing that prevents from hibernation to work properly?
